# data display in gridview with diffent color depends on text in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am displaying student attendance in Gridview from sql server. i choose apsent as A, present as P and leave as L. Now i would like to display A in red color, P in green   in Gridview databind, not for header text. How is it. please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:GridView ID="studentGridView" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="studentGridView_RowDataBound"/>    

protected void studentGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender,GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        const int statusFieldIndex = 1;
        if (e.Row.Cells[statusFieldIndex].Text == "A")
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        //etc
    }
```

statusFieldIndex would be set to the index of the field containing A, L, P, etc

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="studentGridView" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="studentGridView_RowDataBound"/>    

protected void studentGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender,GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        const int statusFieldIndex = 1;
        if (e.Row.Cells[statusFieldIndex].Text == "A")
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        //etc
    }

statusFieldIndex would be set to the index of the field containing A, L, P, etc
if (e.Row.Cells[statusFieldIndex].Text == "A")

In this text is comparing with column header text. but i want to compare binding data(A)

Comment: (e.Row.Cells[statusFieldIndex].Text == "A") In this text is comparing with column header text. but i want to compare binding data(A) –

Comment: e.Row.DataItem contains the source data